# Interstellar: Why did they go to Miller's planet? How was Miller even able to send a green light?

Tags: time-travel, interstellar, wormhole, relativity

Apologies if this has already been answered, but I was not able to find it.  After re-watching Interstellar, I am not able to make sense of the scene where the crew decides to visit Miller's planet, the water-covered one near the black hole.

Lazarus was launched 12 years prior, and given the 2 year trip to the Saturn wormhole, it means Miller would have landed, in Earth's frame of reference, 10 years prior.  The whole crew acknowledges the fact that 1 hour of Miller-time (lol) equals 7 years of Earth-time.  This means that by the time our Brand/Cooper/etc crew makes it near Miller's planet, Miller could have only been on the planet for about 1.5 hours.  The protagonist crew KNOWS that Miller has only been on the planet for 90 minutes of her own time.

So, is the audience expected to believe that in a mere 90 minutes, Miller determined that her planet was a candidate for colonization and sent out multiple green light messages telling NASA to come to her?  I would think it would take at least days, more likely months, to determine a planet was suitable to be the salvation of the human species.  There are other problems with this aspect of the plot as well:

1) Apparently Miller crashed and died, so how and why would she/her ship/her robot send out the green light signal to NASA, along with accompanying data to prove her planet's worth as a future home.

2) Even if she hadn't crashed and died within 90 minutes, HER PLANET WAS NOT INHABITABLE.  It was just a shallow ocean with nothing to offer humanity.  Where was her "good data" even coming from.

In short, to me the Miller planet visit makes no sense.  1) She couldn't have been there for more than 90 minutes, 2) the planet was a colonization dud, and 3) she crashed and died upon trying land there.  So, given those three blockers, how does "we got a signal from Miller telling us her planet was a possibility" even enter the narrative.  It basically implies that IMMEDIATELY (under 90 minutes) upon nearing the planet, Miller, from space, took inaccurate readings about a planet she hadn't even landed on yet which convinced her to send a green light signal back to NASA, a signal that carried the fate of the entire human race.  Then she crashed and died, on planet that turns out to be uninhabitable.

AND, kicker, the crew chose this 90 minutes of data over the YEARS of data the other two scientists had been transmitting.

Bonus question:  How did our crew (and the Lazarus 12 for that matter) get to chose which planets they navigated to.  Seems like they just "entered the wormhole" and magically arrived at the system they wanted to.

Comment: Miller didn't crash and die. She landed, deployed a probe of some sort, and then was killed by a mile-high wave. Presumably, her ship was broken apart by the wave as well.

Comment: As for your bonus question, NASA had sent probes through the wormhole first, which presumably let them determine the positions of many planets among the star systems.

Comment: Because this film is totally illogical and all its premises of action flawed?